# What variables should be passed to a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a test that looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void MyTest_String1IsEmpty_ThrowsException()
{
    string string1 = ""
    string string2 = "b"
    string string3 = "c"

    _myMethod.TestMethod(arg1,arg1,arg1);
}
```

The test is for testing if string1 is empty. My question is, in terms of best practices, should the variables needed to pass to the TestMethod method, be passed in as arguments to the test:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow("", "b", "c")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void MyTest_String1IsEmpty_ThrowsException(string string1, string string2, string string3)
{
    _myMethod.TestMethod(string1,string2,string3);
}
```

The argument I'm testing be passed to the test:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow("")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void MyTest_String1IsEmpty_ThrowsException(string string1)
{
    string string2 = "b"
    string string3 = "c"
    _myMethod.TestMethod(string1,string2,string3);
}
```

Or are the variables fine being set inside the test itself like the first code example?

I see a use case if I was testing multiple values for string1, for example, if I was testing for string1 is null or whitespace, I would just pass the values for String1 to the test and the data rows would be:

```
[DataRow("")]
[DataRow(" ")]
[DataRow(null)]
```

Comment: This is more an opinion based question. Whether you pass it to the test or create it within the test is more based on your preference and the particular scenario. Ideally you just want to give the subject under test what it needs to satisfy the test case. If in this case excluding the other 2 parameters has no undesired effects then they can be excluded altogether. Bat again that is an opinion based on expert experience, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Your example seems to indicate that you are testing a method called `_myMethod.TestMethod`.  This is a very unusual name for a method under test, and I suspect there could be a misunderstanding.  Could you please also show the code for the method under test?

Comment: @DirkHerrmann if i remember correctly, _myMethod would be an instance of a class in the project being tested, for example _myCalculator.Add. Apologies for the confusing names, does that explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments to a test method adds additional complexity and typically only makes sense if you call the test method several times with different arguments - which means that the same test method is used to execute several individual tests which differ by the arguments given.  In that case, the test method is referred to as a parameterized test.

In your example, the name of your test method indicates you are testing one specific scenario, namely that the method under test shall throw an exception if the first argument is an empty string.  There are two possible reasons why parameterization could make sense:

- As you have mentioned, there could be different strings that classify as "empty", like `""`, `" "` and possibly more, and which all should cause the function to throw an exception.  If this is the case, a parameterization on the first argument would make sense (maybe a better term than "empty" could be found in this case).  Otherwise, if "empty string" only denotes `""`, then you would rather not add this as a parameter in order not to cause confusion.
- You would like to execute your test method several times with varying arguments for `string2` and `string3`.  In this case you could pass in the values for `string2` and `string3`.  If in contrast the second and third argument do not have any relevance for the tests and can be chosen arbitrarily, then there is no reason to increase the complexity by turning them into arguments.

If both criteria are fulfilled, then you could in principle address both these testing goals with one parameterized test with three arguments.  In this case, however, you would be using the same test method for testing different aspects.  It could still make sense to do it this way and even let the test framework generate the cartesian product of the inputs automatically for you.  However, to make your testing intent clear, I would recommend to at least add some documentation about the two aspects you would be testing.